# Query UI tab inputs inactive in form

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I'm using `jQuery` ui tabs for a `CakePHP` application, when I submit form after checking multiple checkboxes from category,  it sends the empty checkbox value, here is my view code;

```
$j=1;
$question_id = array();
for($i=0; $i<count($naturestab); $i++){
    echo '<div id="tabs-'.$j++.'">';
    foreach($questionstab as $questiontab){ 
        if($naturestab[$i]['Nature']['id']==$questiontab['Question']['nature_id']){

            $question_id = array($questiontab['Question']['id'] =>  $questiontab['Question']['question'],
            );                                          
            echo $this->Form->input('questions',array(
                'type' => 'select',
                'label'=>false,
                'multiple' => 'checkbox',
                'options'=>$question_id
            ));  
        }
    } 
    echo'</div>';
}
```

Comment: Could you please also add the `$this->Form->create(...)` part and the generated HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

make hidden fields false

```
echo $this->Form->input('questions',array(
            'type' => 'select',
            'label'=>false,
            'hiddenField'=>false,
            'multiple' => 'checkbox',
            'options'=>$question_id
        ));
```